# Async FTP call never ending

Tags: c#, async-await, c#-5.0

I'm trying to find all the ftp servers accepting anonymous connections on a given set of ips.

Basically, I get the IPs I want to check, and then try a ListDirectory on each of them. If I have no exception, the ftp exists and is accessible.

I'm using an asynchronous method to verify an IP, which make things much faster. However, I then need to wait until all the async calls returned. To do this, I keep a counter on the number of async calls I have, **the problem is this counter never gets to 0.**

My code looks as follows:

to iterate over the IPs:

```
static int waitingOn;
public static IEnumerable<Uri> GetFtps()
{
    var result = new LinkedList<Uri>();
    waitingOn = 0;

    IPNetwork ipn = IPNetwork.Parse("192.168.72.0/21");
    IPAddressCollection ips = IPNetwork.ListIPAddress(ipn);

    foreach( var ip in ips )
    {
        VerifyFtpAsync(ip, result);
    }

    while (waitingOn > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(waitingOn);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

    return result;
}
```

and to verify each IP:

```
public async static void VerifyFtpAsync( IPAddress ip, LinkedList<Uri> ftps )
{
    ++waitingOn;
    try
    {
        Uri serverUri = new Uri("ftp://" + ip);
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serverUri);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
        request.Timeout = 10000;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("anonymous", "roim@search.com");

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse) await request.GetResponseAsync();

        // If we got this far, YAY!
        ftps.AddLast(serverUri);
    }
    catch (WebException)
    {
    }
    --waitingOn;
}
```

Comment: Your code seems to be missing the part where you set hsip. Also, it's missing from your call to VerifyFtpAsync. Perhaps there's a VerifyFtpAsync wrapper function.

Comment: Forgot to change those, I was trying to add the Uri's to a HashSet (hsip) to see which calls were not returning, but then at the end my HashSet has 4 null elements (instead of waitingOn == 4).

Comment: I'd start by commenting out the line where you have the await and see if it completes. Sorry, I'm not much help on this one.

Comment: Problem with this is waiting for all the 2000 calls. I'll make the timeout time lower and keep waiting on it. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse) await request.GetResponseAsync();
```

with sync code

```
FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
```

`FtpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync` is not overriden for FTP specific and comes from the base `WebRequest` class, which doesn't seem to be able to handle this right.

Comment: Wow, after 8 years! Thx sir!

Answer (score 1):

First, you should never use `async void` unless you're writing an event handler.

Next, you do need to protect variables and collections against multithreaded access if your `async` methods may run in parallel (e.g., if this code is run in a console app). In your case, it sounds like you may want to use `Task.WhenAll` instead of a manual counter, and remove the shared collection.

```
public async static Task<Uri> VerifyFtpAsync(IPAddress ip)
{
  try
  {
    ...
    return serverUri;
  }
  catch (WebException)
  {
    return null;
  }
}

...

var ipTasks = ips.Select(ip => VerifyFtpAsync(ip));
var allResults = await Task.WhenAll(ipTasks);
var result = allResults.Where(url => url != null).ToArray();
```

Comment: I still don't get why this solves my issues, weren't all the async calls supposed to be executed in a single thread? (I know the awaited thing can run in another thread, but it wasn't accessing any of my variables).
Oh, and +1 for the Linq awesomeness in your response

Comment: @rOim That depends on how are you calling it. If it's from a console application or a `ThreadPool` thread, then the continuations won't be executed on a single thread (unless you're very lucky).

Comment: This solution still hangs sometimes. I modified the ipTasks lines to debug:
var ipTasks = ips.Select(ip => VerifyFtpAsync(ip).ContinueWith(t => { Console.WriteLine(Interlocked.Increment(ref scanned) + "/" + total); return t.Result; }));
and sometimes the output stops at 2047/2048

Comment: Ill leave this as answered and open another more specific question if this continues failing after more investigation. thanks!